# get all spans and click them with puppeteer - fails with "node not visible' and other errors

Tags: javascript, html, click, puppeteer

I have a HTML page that has many div elements, each one with the following structure (the input id and name changes):

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="box">
      <div class="img-block">
         <label for="check-11">
            <input id="check-11"  name="result11" type="checkbox">
            <span class="fake-input"></span>
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to use puppeteer to get all the span with the 'fake-input' class and click on them.
The problem is that it never works, no matter what I try.

In every attempt the start is the same:

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(baseUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

   // FETCHING AND CLICKING
}();
```

I tried many things:

1:

```
await page.waitForSelector('span.fake-input');
await page.click('span.fake-input');
```

2:

```
await page.waitForSelector('span.fake-input')
    .then(()=>{
         console.log(`clicked!`);
         page.click('span.fake-input')
```

3:

```
const spans = await page.evaluate(() => {
     return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span'), el => el.textContent)
 })
 console.log('spans', spans)
 for (let index = 0; index < 7; index++) {
     const element = spans[index];
     await page.click('span')

 }'=
```

4:

```
  await page.evaluate(selector=>{
      return document.querySelector(selector).click();
  },'span.fake-input)
  console.log('clicked');
```

In every solution the page fails to get anything at all (either return null or undefined, so the error is "click" is not a funciton in null) or it fails with the error "Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement".

No matter the error, in any case I fail to fetch all the spans, and click on them.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use [page.$$](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageselector-1) to return multiple elements (equivalent of document.querySelectorAll). Use  [page.$](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageselector) to return a single element (equivalent of document.querySelector).

If you want to extract a certain value from a group of elements, use [page.$$eval](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args)   and [page.$eval](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1)  for a single element.

e.g. return elementHandle to script

```js
const spans = await page.$$('div#item label .fake-input')
spans.forEach(span=>span.click())
```

If you extracting a value from an element, pass a callback to it that returns what you need to extract

e.g.

```js
const spanTexts = page.$$eval('div#item label .fake-input', spans => {
  spans.map(span=>span.innerText)
})
console.log(spanTexts)
```

I should add that page.$$eval and page.$eval executes your callback in the browser context.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = document.querySelectorAll("span.fake-input");
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
   obj[i].click();
}
```

Vanilla JavaScript would work much easier